# android facebook share dialog display

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am using Android SDK and Facebook 3.5 SDK. I am trying to use the share dialog. The share dialog works, but when the dialog appears it places my description string  where the caption is suppose to be (reverses the caption and description) . Is anyone else having this problem and how do you get around it? My code is listed below.

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this, 
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity) this) 

        .setLink(link)
        .setName(name)
        .setCaption(caption)
        .setDescription(description)
        .setPicture(url)
        .build();

        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

so if

name is John Doe
caption is Jane Doe
& description is John Doe and Jane Doe

then instead of getting the following

```
//correct version
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

John Doe and Jane Doe

I get

```
//incorrect version
John Doe
John Doe and Jane Doe
```

Jane Doe

This only happens when the Dialog is showing before being successfully posted. After the post is successful it appears correctly on the timeline. I just want to look correct for cosmetic purposes prior to being posted so that users don't get the wrong impression. Thank you.

Comment: What version of the Facebook app are you using? This was a bug, but should be fixed in the newest version.

Comment: I am using Facebook SDK for Android 3.5.2, I downloaded it directly from FB on 10/3. I am pretty sure this is the newest SDK version. I am thinking that the only way to get around this is to not use the FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder but instead just settle with the WebDialog since the WebDialog works flawlessly. I am still searching for a solution to the  FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder

Comment: I'm talking about the Facebook app, not the SDK. Since the share dialog is rendered by the Facebook app, you should download the latest app.

Comment: I am using Version 3.7 for samsung galaxy s4. As far as I can tell I am using the latest version.

Comment: A new version was released yesterday.